# PHP for date how to display

Tags: php, wordpress, date, custom-fields

I have this code which display my custom field and an image next to it if the custom field is populated

```
<?php
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_eventstartdate', true);
if( !empty($value)) {
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/date1.gif">';
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

It's from a datepicker field in wordpress and I can't for love nor money work out how to get it to display the date correctly even when replacing $value with something like this:

```
string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ]
```

Comment: What format is `ecpt_eventstartdate` in?

Comment: I didn't ask what it was, I asked what format it was in.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being dumb, it's $dateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
new Date(date('Y-m-d'));
```

that should do the trick

Comment: thanks! so this you mean:

'<?php
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_eventstartdate', true);
if( !empty($value)) {
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/date1.gif">';
    echo new Date(date('Y-m-d'));
}
?>'

Answer (score 0):

The question is what is current output/ what's inside $value?

If it's a unix timestamp (like 1360954102), then Guerra is right and you are supposed to do it like this:`echo date('Y-m-d',$value);`

If the current format is a string and the date is just not formatted as you wish it to, then you will first need to transfer $value back to a timestring (for example using strtotime() or explode() + mktime() ), before you can then use date() to reformat it again.

If this doesn't solve your problem please post what's inside of $value and how it is supposed to be formatted. :-)